# Clarification on when is $X_T$ integrable (martingale theory)

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

I have the following homework problem, and I have already done the (a)-part. I am confused as to what condition (b) actually means: does it mean that

1. there exists $C$ such that whenever $T(\omega)\geq n$, we have $|X_n(\omega)|\leq C$ (except perhaps for $\omega$ in some null set), or
2. there exists $C$ such that if $n\leq T$ holds for all $\omega$, then $|X_n|\leq C$ holds a.s.

[image]

I don't think the second alternative is enough to imply that $X_T$ is integrable, but I would appreciate a clarification here.

Comment: They mean interpretation (1), the "for all" is referring to the $n$, not the $T$

Comment: How is $X_{\infty}$ defined? For example the stopping time could be infinite on a set of non-zero measure (usually we assume it is a.s. finite). But yes, interpretation $1$ is the right one.

Comment: Thank you. The definition of $X_\infty$ has been swept under the carpet thus far in the course, so I'm not entirely sure what to make of that case either.